# Can we install Xcache 2.0 or 3 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: webserver, cache

Xcache have already reached the version 3.0. But in Ubuntu 12.04, we still have version 1. How can we install Xcache 2 or 3 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xcache 2.0.0-2 is backported for precise by blubolt team.

You can download the .deb files from [here](https://launchpad.net/~blubolt/+archive/preciseplatform/+sourcepub/2621572/+listing-archive-extra)

Alternate way to get 2.0.0-2 is to add the blubolt preciseplatform PPA

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/blubolt/preciseplatform/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/blubolt/preciseplatform/ubuntu precise main
```

For more information https://launchpad.net/~blubolt/+archive/preciseplatform

Comment: Is it safe? Will it break stuff?

Comment: I'm on Quantal and I run the latest version and it working fine. Not sure about precise. You can try out :)